# Not able to call another page through router in view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

This is my current structure.

[image: Folder Structure]

main.js

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min',
    underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
    backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone-min',
    handlebars: 'libs/handlebars/handlebars-v1.3.0',
    templates : '../templates/',

  }

});

require([
  'app',
], function(App){
  App.initialize();
});
```

app.js

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'router',
  'handlebars'
], function($, _, Backbone, Router, Handlebars){
  var initialize = function(){

    Router.initialize();
  }

  return {
    initialize: initialize
  };
});
```

router.js

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'handlebars',
  'views/login',
  'views/home'
], function ($, _, Backbone, Handlebars, LoginBox, HomePage) {
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            'login': 'login',
            'home': 'home',
        },
        login: function () {
            var loginbox = new LoginBox();
            loginbox.render();
        },
        home: function () {
            var homepage = new HomePage();
            homepage.render();
        }
    });
    var initialize = function () {
        var app_router = new AppRouter;
        Backbone.history.start();
    };
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

login.js

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'handlebars',
  'text!templates/login.html',
  'router'
], function ($, _, Backbone, Handlebars, loginHTML, router) {

    var LoginBox = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: $('.middle-container'),
        initialize: function () {
            this.router = require('router');    // MagiC
            this.router.navigate('home');       // Lines
        },
        render: function () {
            var data = {};
            var compiledTemplate = _.template(loginHTML, data);
            this.$el.append(compiledTemplate);
        },
        events: {
            "click #submit": "login"
        },
        login: function (event) {

            var url = 'http://192.168.1.132:3000/api/login/';
            var formValues = {
                username: $('#username').val(),
                password: $('#password').val()
            };
            console.log("sending " + formValues);
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                //dataType:"json",
                data: formValues,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(["Login request details: ", data]);

                    /*I've been doing more magic here*/
                    //Router.initialize();
                    //Backbone.history.navigate("home", true);
                    //that.navigate("home", {});
                    //routerddd = new that();
                    //routerddd.navigate("home");


                    if (data.error) { 
                        alert("Errrorrroror : " + data.error);
                    } else { 
                        //More error
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return LoginBox;
});
```

All right, enough of the code. I have been trying to redirect user from `login` page to `home` page if ajax call was successful in `login.js`. I am getting the console log when the ajax request is successful but not able to redirect the page to home. However i have tried too many things that i can't explain here now. So, if there is any error in configuring the require js or any other way to navigate user to home page `(calling route:home)` when  ajax request is successful. Kindly guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your success callback function use the code bellow.

```
Backbone.history.navigate("#/home");
```

It should work.

But i guess that you're mistaking how backbone communicate with the server.
You should use Backbone.Model save(),fetch(), destroy() function to integrate with the server.

You're doing a good job with requireJS exposing only what you want expose from a module, and this is a good pattern.

I just think that you could use models instead of Jquery Ajax.

Note that Backbone use jquery behinds.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey amigo, I tried that and that doesn't work. Actually i made some changes and now i am able to call router too. In both cases i found that the url is changing but the page is not!!! i am patching through `location.reload();` but that's not an solution. What could be the possible error? Should i post updated codes?